# Updating the image of a NSStatusItem

Tags: cocoa, user-interface, statusbar

I have a statusItem in the StatusBar. I've retained a reference to it in my class.
Now, I want to update the image of the item.
In order to this, I wrote a method similar to:

```
-(void)updateStatusIcon:(NSString *)newImage
{
    [statusItem setImage:[NSImage imageNamed:newImage]];
}
```

The image is a valid icon and works when I set it initially so I know the image is fine.
When this code executes, the statusItem disappears from the StatusBar completely.

Any idea what the best way to update the image on a NSStatusItem is?

Comment: Are you sure you are getting the value you are expecting in newImage parameter?

Comment: It appears you've flagged Marc's response as an answer. Would you mind explaining how you fixed this issue?

Comment: I was just doing something silly in my code - the snippet above correct once I fixed paths to the new image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's the correct way to set the status item image. There's a problem either with your image or somewhere else in your code.